# LinkedIn share button weird behavior

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement a LinkedIn share button with a counter. I have used to button that was generated on the site but that didn't work. Now I found another method that works on a test site of mine, but when I implement it in my final site it shows some weird behavior.

Sometimes it shows up on where it should be, and sometimes it just shows up on the bottom left of the site (all the way down) and it's not clickable.

The code I've used is:

```
<h1> Linkedin share </h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script>
<script type="in/share" data-counter="right" data-success="LinkedInShare"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">LinkedInShare();</script>

<!-- Google Analytics Social Button Tracking -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ga_social_tracking.js"></script>
<!-- LinkedIn Share Button tracking-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function LinkedInShare() {
_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'LinkedIn', 'Share']);
}
</script>
```

Has anyone had the same problem? Or can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using ASP.NET and C# in my web application

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a JS or CSS issue with your markup and the plugin. You should go the the LinkedIn Developer site and post an issue in the forums with the URL of a page that can reproduce the issue.

Also, FYI, the data-success callback is currently broken. It will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure the LinkedIn share button works properly, is to use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

instead of other alternatives.